# Storing matrix colum sums and comparing them to find the largest

Tags: c, matrix, compare, store

How do I store 1,2,3...n columns sums to a variable and than compare them to find the largest sum?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define NUM_ITEMS 1000

int array[NUM_ITEMS];

int main(){
    FILE* file;
    int a[10][10];
    int i,j, count = 0;
    int n=0;

    file = fopen("Matrica.txt", "r");

    while(count < NUM_ITEMS && fscanf(file, "%d", &array[count]) == 1)
        count++;

    n = sqrt(count);

    printf("Dimenzije matrice: %dx%d ",n,n);

    rewind(file);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        fscanf(file,"%d",&a[i][j]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf("\nElementi matrice: %d \n",a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    int col[n];

    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            col[i] += a[i][0];
        }
    }
    printf("\nDBG:%d",col[0]);
    fclose(file);  
}
```

The task is to find dimensions of `a[10][10]`, print out the elements of it and find the column that has biggest sum. What is the name for this var in English.
So far I've finished 2/3rds of the task.

Below is the code:

```c
for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            col[i] += a[i][0];
        }
    }
```

it is the code for calculating sum of the 1st column.

I don't know how to implement it to do what I want, because `col[i]` must have NULL values for sum to take it's place
or it will just print out a bunch a jibberish.

**Note:** `col[0]` was supposed to present column 1 , `col[1]` column 2 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I guessed correctly from the example you get only one 10x10 matrix from file, and now you want to sum elements in columns(vertically) not in rows(horizontally) try changing

```
col[i] += a[i][0]
```

to

```
col[i] += a[j][i]
```

Because with your code you were only adding first element of every row. First `[]` indicates row,second `[]` indicates column. What this slight change does is it sums every column element of row to its column index in `col[i]`. Because I don't know how your text file looks like I suppose you for sure get 10x10 matrix with valid elements.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion the 0 is in there just for testing purposes I am aware of that mistake but you see col[i] gets jibberish values since it has nothing in it and adding values from columns just boosts that random number so I can't properly compare them.
The point of the col array is to store column sum values in 0,1,2...n and than compare those to see which column has the biggest sum of elements.

Comment: that's because when you initialize col [ n ] you get random value for every element, I didn't seen that part sorry and I should have.. what you need you do is set every element to 0, than do sum. You can do than simply:

int col [ n ] = { 0 };

that should set every element to 0, than change your line with my line and that should be it.

Comment: **Thank you so much ! This was my main problem.
Task solved and completed.**

Comment: Nista maci sve 5 :D